# Modify price adjustment of configurable products through API.

Tags: product, database, model, configurable-product

I'm trying to modify my configurable attributes options that I have set in Magento, but upon save I recieve a PDO error saying that it's a duplicate. I haven't been able to find a way to set these through catalog/product, catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute, or catalog/product_type_configurable but this was my best and most understandable attempt. Can anyone tell me the best way to change this data? Thank you!

```
// Get a collection of all the configurables
$productConfig = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');
foreach($productConfig as $product) {
    // Get an array of all of the configurable products and their options
    $product_attribute_options = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableOptions($product);
    $product_attribute_options = array_shift($product_attribute_options);
    foreach($product_attribute_options as & $child) {
        // Adjust arrays price in here
    }
    // Get a new fresh product just in case the collection product doesn't have everything. 
    $config_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $config_product->load($product->getId());
    // Set and save
    $config_product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $config_product->setConfigurableAttributesData($product_attribute_options);
    $config_product->save();
}
```

And here is the PDO error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2864-0' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID'' in /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#1 /lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pd in /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being the array_shift, I ended up extending the foreach loop and it works now.